# Laravel getting id from database to download pdf blade

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am using dompdf currently and I encounter this issue where the id returns me pdf instead of the value I want such as 2 or 1 or 3.

Route:

```
Route::get('pdfview/{id}',array('as'=>'pdfview','uses'=>'pdfDownloadController@pdfview'));
```

I get the id pdf when I do something like this:

```
 public function pdfview($id)
    {
        dd($id); --> return id = pdf
    $object = UserInfo::where('id',$id)->get();
    dd($object); --> return empty collection
}

Collection {#395 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

I get the id as null when I do like this:

```
    public function pdfview(Request $request)
    {
         $id = UserInfo::find($request->id);
         dd($id);
}
```

test.blade.php (use this link to download the file)

```
<a href="{{ route('pdfview',['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the problem in this  tag you have.

test.blade.php (use this link to download the file) 'pdf']) }}">Download PDF

You are passing the string 'pdf' to the route. thats is the same string it returns back to you. you are suppose to pass the actual ID inside your VIEW file. this way it returns an integer that comes from database.

EX:

```
 <a href="{{url('/pdfview')}}/{{$post->id}}">Download PDF</a>
```

In that example $post->id is the ID of the $post it coming from database, and thats what you need to pass to that route and to be able to fetch more data from database based on that ID.

Hopefully it make sense now.

Comment: The $post should it be $id? Taken from the controller,  public function pdfview($id)

Comment: no, the $post->id is the ID of that post which needs to be passed to the ROUTE.

Comment: Ok I understand what you meant. Thank you so much for helping me. It finally work :)

Comment: Just want to ask do you want to remove the other question? It seems like the other question are comments. Because among all the answer this answer here is the one that help me :)

Comment: Please Add Exact URL from HTML file. so i can see what you passing to the url.

after clicking the tag you can look at the browser URL and see if an ID is passing after http://localhost//pdfview/2

or its http://localhost//pdfview/pdf if your url is just like this ends with string 'pdf', then you need to change it the id instead.

Please share your exact HTML tag that way i can help better.